# Certbot - Cannot find Apache control command apachectl

Tags: apache, centos, certbot

I have a VPS setup with Centos 6, with the new Apple requirements for HTTPS access I was looking at using Certbot. Now the problem is I go through the setup process and the following error pops up

> The apache plugin is not working; there may be problems with your
>   existing configuration. The error was: NoInstallationError('Cannot
>   find Apache control command apachectl',)

When I run the following

> find / -name apachectl

I get

> /home/cpeasyapache/src/httpd-2.4/support/apachectl
>   /usr/local/apache.backup/bin/apachectl /usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl

Is there a way I can alter the config so that the system can use apachectl. The system came pre-built from UK2.

Thanks